# How to correctly secure a .VHD file on a multiuser system?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, mount, vhd

I am trying to create a .VHD that is mounted on boot with `Mount-DiskImage`. I don't want users to mess with it, so I removed all permissions except `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` who have full access.

Now `Mount-DiskImage` works and does not report any errors. However, once logged in, I cannot access the disk in Explorer, seeing "Access denied" error. In fact, the only way I see the disk is from elevated programs. The same problem applies to any unprivileged users.

It seems that despite the fact, that the file system on .VHD permits Full access to regular users it somehow inherits the permissions of the .VHD file itself. My expectation was that the service/driver that mounts the disk will ignore the .VHD file permissions, and would only need read/write for itself.

The problem I see with the approach Windows seems to be taking here is that with permissive ACL on the .VHD regular users could mess with the .VHD file when it is not in the mounted state.

How do I properly secure the .VHD file?

Comment: Encryption is the way to go.

Comment: @mashuptwice encryption won't prevent users from overwriting the whole file.

Comment: Oh, you are not worried about someone reading or writing into the VHD, but to overwrite it or delete it. Set owner and permissions to a standard user and use encryption, otherwise someone with access to the hardware or able to boot from an USB stick would still be able to mess with your file.